# Not able to bind kernel threads to CPU

Tags: multithreading, linux-kernel, cpu

I have written this code to bind 2 kernel threads to different CPUs :

```
#include<linux/kthread.h>
#include<linux/sched.h>
#include<linux/delay.h>
#include<linux/slab.h>

struct task_struct *task1;
struct task_struct *task2;
int cpu, data;

int thread_function_one(void *data)
{
    int ret = 10;
    printk(KERN_INFO "IN THREAD FUNCTION 1 \n");

    while(!kthread_should_stop()){
       cpu = get_cpu();
       put_cpu();
       printk("t1 cpu = %d\n",cpu);
       msleep(5000);
    }
    printk(KERN_INFO "EXIT from thread function 1\n");
    return ret;
}

int thread_function_two(void *data)
{
    int ret = 10;
    printk(KERN_INFO "IN THREAD FUNCTION 2 \n");

    while(!kthread_should_stop()){
        cpu = get_cpu();
        put_cpu();
        printk("t2 cpu = %d\n",cpu);
        msleep(6000);
    }
    printk(KERN_INFO "EXIT from thread function 2\n");
    return ret;
}

static int kernel_init(void)
{
   printk(KERN_INFO "module_init\n");

   cpu = get_cpu();
   put_cpu();
   printk("main thread cpu = %d \n",cpu);

   task1 = kthread_create(&thread_function_one,(void *)&data,"one");
   kthread_bind(task1, cpu);
   wake_up_process(task1);

   cpu = 5;
   task2 = kthread_create(&thread_function_two,(void *)&data,"two");
   kthread_bind(task2, cpu);
   wake_up_process(task2);

   return 0;
}

static void kernel_exit(void)
{
   kthread_stop(task1);
   kthread_stop(task2);
   printk(KERN_INFO "module_exit\n");
}

module_init(kernel_init);
module_exit(kernel_exit);
MODULE_AUTHOR("K_K");
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

**But when I print the cpu id in thread_function_one and thread_function_two both print the same CPU as that of main thread.**

Am I doing smthing wrong ?

Output of this prog :

```
kernel: [  956.816510] module_init
kernel: [  956.816515] main thread cpu = 8 
kernel: [  956.816743] IN THREAD FUNCTION 1 
kernel: [  956.816748] t1 cpu = 8
kernel: [  956.817057] IN THREAD FUNCTION 2 
kernel: [  956.817062] t2 cpu = 8
kernel: [  961.815160] t1 cpu = 8
kernel: [  962.814649] t2 cpu = 8
kernel: [  966.816760] t1 cpu = 8
kernel: [  968.815711] t2 cpu = 8
kernel: [  971.818307] EXIT from thread function 1
kernel: [  974.816813] EXIT from thread function 2
kernel: [  974.816872] module_exit
```

Comment: Try to print the cpu_mask of each kthread before and after calling kthread_bind

Comment: my bad, I have kept the "int cpu" variable as global thats why getting this error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The module works fine if the "int cpu" variable is not global. The thread one modifies this global and  thread two binds itself to the same CPU. This is the race condition between main thread, thread one and thread two.